# Washer stand pipe and floor drain question

Tags: plumbing, drain, washer

I imagine this is a common setup. My questions concern how the standpipe and the floor drain are trapped and connected to the sewer line. Can I know with any certain how these are connected under the slab?

I can see that the current standpipe empties into the floor drain just under slab.  I suspect that the floor drain trap acts as the trap for standpipe and the standpipe does not have a trap.

I am moving the washer and dryer upstairs and the horizontal pipe emptying into the stack will be rerouted. It currently is used for a toilet. I was originally planning on using this horizontal run to empty the new standpipe into the stack but I am wondering if that will prevent the floor drain trap from being primed with water. Instead, can I run the new stand pipe line into the old one? If so, do I still need a trap at the new laundry room above floor level?  If there is a trap under the current standpipe, I would think that two traps in the line would not work.

[image]

Comment: *"I was planning on using this pipe to empty the new stand pipe into the stack but I am wondering if that will keep the floor drain trap from being primed with water"* Why would using the horizontal pipe (currently for a toilet) have anything to do with the floor drain pictured? How would that have any effect? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I was not clear enough. Fixing now...

Comment: I think I am quite sure that there is no trap for the existing stand pipe in the basement. Or simply empties out into the floor drain and the floor drain has a trap for sewer gases. Do I need a trap upstairs if I am simply going to tie the drain into the existing stand pipe?